# How can we validate the below dropdownlist in mvc3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In view I have and I am not able to validate the below mvc code

```
       @Html.DropDownList("PriorityId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Priority, "--Please Select One--", new { @id = "ddlPriority", @class = "dropdown" })
```

In Controller I have

```
       private void PriorityDropdownList()
       {
           IEnumerable<SelectListItem> priorityDropdownlist =_PriorityObj.PriorityDropdownlistGet();
           if (priorityDropdownlist != null)
           {
               ViewBag.Priority = priorityDropdownlist;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using **ViewBag / ViewData** for sending data to your view. Use strongly typed views & ViewModels with data annotations as required for validation.

```
public class CreateIssueVM
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> Priorities { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int SelectedPriority { set;get;}
}
```

Here i have decorated the `Name` and `SelectedPriority` properties with `Required` attributes. That means, user needs to enter these, otherwise, it will bring up the validation message of form submit.

In your `GET` action , set the collection property value and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new CreateIssueVM();
  vm.Priorities =GetPriorities();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetPriorities`  method returns a collection of `SelectListItem` for the priorities.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetPriorities()
{
  List<SelectListItem> prioList=new List<SelectListItem>();
  prioList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1" });
  prioList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "2" });
  // to do :read from db and add to list instead of hardcoding
  return prioList;
}
```

Now in our view, which is strongly typed to `CreateIssueVM`

```
@model CreateIssueVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedPriority,
                     new SelectList(Model.Priorities ,"Value","Text"),"select")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.SelectedPriority)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

When you submit the form, you can check the form is valid or not by checking the `ModelState.IsValid` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateIssueVM model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // save and redirect
  }
  vm.Priorities =GetPriorities();
  return View(vm);
}
```

If you want to implement client side validation as well, you may simply include the relevant jquery unobtrusive validation scripts in the view and enable the client side validation in web.config.